# Worker start to fail CSINodeIfo: error updating CSINode annotation

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I created a  kubernetes cluster 1 master and 2 worker nodes 2 months ago, 
today one worker node started to fail and I don't know why. I think nothing unusual happened to my worker.

I used flannel and kubeadm to create the cluster and it was working very well.

If I describe the node:

```
tommy@bxybackend:~$ kubectl describe node bxybackend-node01
Name:               bxybackend-node01
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=bxybackend-node01
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
Annotations:        flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VtepMAC":"06:ca:97:82:50:10"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 10.168.10.4
                    kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Sun, 03 Nov 2019 09:41:48 -0600
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                    node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:17:05 -0600   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 10:37:19 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:17:05 -0600   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 10:37:19 -0600   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:17:05 -0600   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 10:37:19 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:17:05 -0600   Wed, 11 Dec 2019 10:37:19 -0600   KubeletNotReady              Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.168.10.4
  Hostname:    bxybackend-node01
Capacity:
 cpu:                12
 ephemeral-storage:  102684600Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             14359964Ki
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                12
 ephemeral-storage:  94634127204
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             14257564Ki
 pods:               110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 3afa24bb05994ceaaf00e7f22b9322ab
 System UUID:                80951742-F69F-6487-F2F7-BE2FB7FEFBF8
 Boot ID:                    115fbacc-143d-4007-90e4-7fdcb5462680
 Kernel Version:             4.15.0-72-generic
 OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.9.7
 Kubelet Version:            v1.17.0
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.17.0
PodCIDR:                     10.244.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                    10.244.1.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:         (2 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                           CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----                           ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sslbg    100m (0%)     100m (0%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      8m31s
  kube-system                kube-proxy-c5gxc               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         8m52s
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                100m (0%)  100m (0%)
  memory             50Mi (0%)  50Mi (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                  From                           Message
  ----     ------                   ----                 ----                           -------
  Warning  SystemOOM                52m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     System OOM encountered, victim process: dotnet, pid: 12170
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    52m (x12 over 38d)   kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     52m (x12 over 38d)   kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeNotReady             52m (x6 over 23d)    kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeNotReady
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  52m (x12 over 38d)   kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Warning  ContainerGCFailed        52m (x3 over 6d23h)  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   NodeReady                52m (x13 over 38d)   kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Warning  SystemOOM                43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     System OOM encountered, victim process: dotnet, pid: 9699
  Warning  SystemOOM                43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     System OOM encountered, victim process: dotnet, pid: 12639
  Warning  SystemOOM                43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     System OOM encountered, victim process: dotnet, pid: 16194
  Warning  SystemOOM                43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     System OOM encountered, victim process: dotnet, pid: 19618
  Warning  SystemOOM                43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     System OOM encountered, victim process: dotnet, pid: 12170
  Normal   Starting                 43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  43m (x2 over 43m)    kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     43m (x2 over 43m)    kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeNotReady             43m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeNotReady
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    43m (x2 over 43m)    kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Node bxybackend-node01 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   Starting                 42m                  kubelet, bxybackend-node01     Starting kubelet.
```

If I watch syslog in the worker:

```
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.552152   19331 kuberuntime_manager.go:981] updating runtime config through cri with podcidr 10.244.1.0/24
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.552162   19331 kubelet_node_status.go:294] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.552352   19331 docker_service.go:355] docker cri received runtime config &RuntimeConfig{NetworkConfig:&NetworkConfig{PodCidr:10.244.1.0/24,},}
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.552600   19331 kubelet_network.go:77] Setting Pod CIDR:  -> 10.244.1.0/24
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.555142   19331 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Attempting to register node bxybackend-node01
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.652843   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kube-proxy" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configmap/d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089-kube-proxy") pod "kube-proxy-c5gxc" (UID: "d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753179   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "xtables-lock" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/host-path/d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089-xtables-lock") pod "kube-proxy-c5gxc" (UID: "d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753249   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "lib-modules" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/host-path/d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089-lib-modules") pod "kube-proxy-c5gxc" (UID: "d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753285   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kube-proxy-token-ztrh4" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089-kube-proxy-token-ztrh4") pod "kube-proxy-c5gxc" (UID: "d6b534db-c32c-491b-a665-cf1ccd6cd089")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753316   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "run" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/host-path/6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2-run") pod "kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sslbg" (UID: "6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753342   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "cni" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/host-path/6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2-cni") pod "kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sslbg" (UID: "6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753461   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "flannel-cfg" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configmap/6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2-flannel-cfg") pod "kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sslbg" (UID: "6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753516   19331 reconciler.go:209] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "flannel-token-ts2qt" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2-flannel-token-ts2qt") pod "kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sslbg" (UID: "6a2299cf-63a4-4e96-8b3b-acd373de12c2")
Dec 11 11:20:10 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:10.753531   19331 reconciler.go:156] Reconciler: start to sync state
Dec 11 11:20:12 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:12.052813   19331 kubelet_node_status.go:112] Node bxybackend-node01 was previously registered
Dec 11 11:20:12 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: I1211 11:20:12.052921   19331 kubelet_node_status.go:73] Successfully registered node bxybackend-node01
Dec 11 11:20:13 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: E1211 11:20:13.051159   19331 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Dec 11 11:20:16 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: E1211 11:20:16.051264   19331 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Dec 11 11:20:18 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: E1211 11:20:18.451166   19331 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Dec 11 11:20:21 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: E1211 11:20:21.251289   19331 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Dec 11 11:20:25 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: E1211 11:20:25.019276   19331 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Dec 11 11:20:46 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: E1211 11:20:46.772862   19331 csi_plugin.go:267] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo: error updating CSINode annotation: timed out waiting for the condition; caused by: the server could not find the requested resource
Dec 11 11:20:46 bxybackend-node01 kubelet[19331]: F1211 11:20:46.772895   19331 csi_plugin.go:281] Failed to initialize CSINodeInfo after retrying
Dec 11 11:20:46 bxybackend-node01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Dec 11 11:20:46 bxybackend-node01 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: i just see that the trouble node is in another version NAME                STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
bxybackend          Ready      master   38d   v1.16.2
bxybackend-node01   NotReady   <none>   38d   v1.17.0
bxybackend-node02   Ready      <none>   38d   v1.16.2

Answer (score 11):

During your kubeadm install your are supposed to run the following command to hold  kubelet, kubeadm and kubectl packages and prevent them from getting upgraded mistakenly.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

I've reproduced your scenario and what happened to your cluster is that 3 days ago, a new version of Kubernetes was released (v 1.17.0) and your kubelet got got upgraded accidentally.

On the new Kubernetes some changes where made on [CSI](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.17.md#changes) and that's why you have some problems in this node.

I suggest you to drain this node, setup a new one with Kubernetes 1.16.2 and join the new one to your cluster.

To drain this node you need to run:

```
$ kubectl drain bxybackend-node01 --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
```

Optionally you can downgrade your kubelet to previous version using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kubelet=1.16.2-00
```

Don't forget to mark your kubelet to prevent it from being upgraded again:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold kubelet
```

You can use the command `apt-mark showhold` to list all held packages and make sure kubelet, kubeadm and kubectl are on hold.

**To upgrade from 1.16.x to 1.17.x follow this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/) from Kubernetes Documentation. I've validated it and it works as intended.**

Comment: I'm running into the same problem where it looks like kubernetes was automatically updated to 1.17.0. None of my nodes are reporting ready including the master. Are you suggesting reverting to 1.16.2?

Comment: Faced same issue after a routine patching of the servers in the test environment.

Comment: Reverting to 1.16.4 worked, is there any recommendations on how to move to 1.17?

Comment: @CodeJunkie I've added information about how to upgrade to 1.17.

Comment: Thanks, I followed that same guide yesterday and was able to update with success. Is there away to build scripts to automatically handle these updates while patching?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this could be due to a version mismatch. A higher kubelet version ( > 1.17) against a 1.16 API server, which is not supported.

You can fix this by upgrading your control plane version to 1.17 or higher. If that's not an immediate option, in the worker nodes, update **/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml** with the below entries:

```
featureGates:
  CSIMigration: false
```

Reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/86094

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue today on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908. My kubernetes version was v1.16.3 and I executed "yum update" command and kubernetes version upgraded to v1.17.0. After that I did "yum history undo "no" and then reverted back to old kubernetes version and it was started working again. After that I followed the official upgrade method and now kubernetes v1.17.0 is working fine without any issue.

```
root@kube-master1:/root>kubectl get no -o wide
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION               CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kube-master1   Ready    master   7d9h   v1.17.0   192.168.159.135   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
kube-worker1   Ready    worker   7d9h   v1.17.0   192.168.159.136   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
kube-worker2   Ready    worker   7d9h   v1.17.0   192.168.159.137   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
root@kube-master1:/root>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post!  It would be great if you could post a link to the `official upgrade method`!

Comment: @Mark, in my post you can find [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/) link to the oficial documentation where it's described how to do it on Ubuntu, Debian, HypriotOS, CentOS, RHEL or Fedora.